# Filter DataGridView based on ComboBox selection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is the view on my `DataGridView`. I want to filter environment based on the selection in `ComboBox`. The data has been populated from xml

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1) Populate the combobox manually, first adding "All", then adding the items from industryGroupsDataSet.Tables[0].

2) Add a BindingSource between companiesDataSet.Tables[0] and dataGridView1.DataSource.

3) In the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox, alter the Filter property of the BindingSource. If the selected index is zero ("All"), set the Filter to null, otherwise set the filter to String.Format("groupID = '{0}'", cmbBxGroupFilter.SelectedValue).

Obtained from here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/de807368-afa0-4bfe-bc8f-7c52746d60c9/filter-datagridview-based-on-combo-box-selection?forum=winforms